# Finding which value I will be on after a certain number of steps

Tags: arrays

I have a fixed array: `[a,b,c]`, I wanna loop through this 3-items-sized array for 7 times in order to find what I would get at that exact step.

The "value stack" for `7` would look like `a b c a b c a`.

Question is, how can I find what value would be at step `10`, for example?

---

Input: `getValueForStep( [a,b,c], 7 )`

Output: `a`

Comment: `I wanna` [consider what is and isn't on-topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [appropriate with CS@SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange).

Answer (score 1):

A simple observation is that, with 0-based indices:

```
final_index = (elements_traversed - 1) mod array_length
```

For example, for `array_length = 3` and `elements_traversed = 7`, `final_index = (7 - 1) mod 3 = 0` (corresponding to the first element).